# How can I perform add to a Particular number in a linked list?

Tags: java, linked-list

Am writing this Java networking program with linked list. The program adds the details of every node that contacts it and then prints it out. During the printing i want 1 to be added to *Infor* every time as I would be printing the details 10 times using a for loop.

error is occurring at this part:

```
list.get(lastPostion).getInfor()+1;
```

Below is my code.

```
public class Linked {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        workPls oks = new workPls();
        try {
            DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(Integer.parseInt(args[0]));
            socket.setSoTimeout(0);
            while (true) {

                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
                socket.receive(packet);
                int data = 0;
                PlsWork ok = new PlsWork(packet.getAddress(), "pc1", data);

                oks.addNode(ok);
                oks.print();
            }
        } catch (Exception error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}


public class PlsWork {

    private InetAddress IP;
    private String PC;
    private int Infor;

    public PlsWork(InetAddress IP, String PC, int Infor) {
        this.IP = IP;
        this.PC = PC;
        this.Infor = Infor;
    }

    public InetAddress getIP() {
        return IP;
    }

    public String getPC() {
        return PC;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return IP + " " + PC;
    }

    public int getInfor() {
        return Infor;
    }

}
public class workPls {

    private LinkedList<PlsWork> list = new LinkedList<>();
    private InetAddress ip;
    private int lastPostion = 0;

    public void addNode(PlsWork st) {
        list.add(st);
    }

    public LinkedList getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public void print() {

        for (int i = 0; i > 10; i++) {
            System.out.println(list);
            System.out.println(list.get(lastPostion).getIP());
            list.get(lastPostion).getInfor() + 1;
            lastPostion+=1;
        }

    }

    public InetAddress getip() {
        return ip;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`list.get(lastPostion).getInfor() + 1` adds two `int`s and does nothing with the result. In order to modify the `Infor` instance variable of a `PlsWork` instance, you must call another method.

Either add a `void setInfor(int newValue)` method to `PlsWork` and call:

```
PlsWork current = list.get(lastPostion);
current.setInfor(current.getInfor() + 1);
```

Or add a `void incrementInfor()` method to `PlsWork` and call:

```
list.get(lastPostion).incrementInfor();
```

Also note that you have an unrelated typo in your for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i > 10; i++)
```

should be

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
```